# list modified files in list of svn revisions

Tags: eclipse, svn, redmine

svn offer lot of nice commands that make us able to know what is/did happening in our repository.

i am loking for a command that allows me to list the files that has been modified in a specific revisions (note a range, but a list of some specific revisions).

**Exemple:**

i'd like to know what are the files that have been modified in the revisions: 624 , 625, 630,631

but i'd like to groupe this by files (if a file has been modified in revision 624 and 630, i'd like it to be whan once)

svn diff --summarize .... can make this but for a range of revision, in my case the range is not possible to have.

PS:
i'm using redmine, so if the solution is there, it'd be nice also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way to do that in either Subversion or Redmine.  I'd suggest writing a small script that repeatedly calls svn diff, and then processes the results.

As an example, here's a quick way to do it via the command line:

```
echo "255 318 319 320" | perl -p -e 's/ /\n/g' | xargs -I {} svn diff . --summarize -c {} | perl -p -e 's/^...\s*//' | sort | uniq
```